# File not found exception while trying to play sound with MediaPlayer

Tags: android, netbeans, audio

I'm developing an Android app with NetBeans, and I'm trying to play a sound with

```
MediaPlayer mp;
mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.a);
mp.start();
```

There is a file named "a.mp3" in the res/raw directory, but for some reason I'm getting a file not found exception on line 2. What's the problem?

Comment: Works fine for me have you made sure you refreshed your project after adding the sound? or double checked it is actually in the right folder.

Comment: hi, i refreshed and double check, there is no error on "R.raw.a" when i am complying. just in run time.

Answer (score 0):

I was actually able to get a file named `a.wma` to play simply by changing the name. Try to name it to something like `a1.wma` and see if it makes a difference.

Some names appear to give errors due to conflicting with a function or something similar in the coding language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is even relevant anymore...
But did you try surrounding the statements with try and catch blocks? What does it say?